# JUnit Testing for a simple facade

Tags: java, junit

Trying to come up with a JUnit test for the following facade - I know this should be simple but I keep coming up blank. Any ideas to get me going in the right direction.  It doesn't need to be complicated - I just need to get it done.

```
package business;

import domain.Items;
import services.exceptions.ItemNotFoundException;
import services.itemservice.IItemsService;

public class Itemmgr {

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void store(Items item) {
        Factory factory = Factory.getInstance(IItemsService.NAME);

        IItemsService storeItem = (IItemsService)factory.getInstance(IItemsService.NAME);

        storeItem.storeItem(item);
    }

    public void get(Items item) throws ClassNotFoundException, ItemNotFoundException { 
        Factory factory = Factory.getInstance(IItemsService.NAME);

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        IItemsService getItem = (IItemsService)factory.getInstance(IItemsService.NAME);

        try {
            getItem.getItems("pens", 15, "red", "gel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | ItemNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error - Class or Item Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test? To see if everything is stored correctly?

Comment: yeah - just a basic test of functionality

Comment: store a couple of items, then try to get them, and see if the gotten items match up with the stored items. Unless if you provide more details on what you want to check, I really can't be more specific.

Comment: If you're looking to code up a true "unit test", you'll probably want to create mocks for your database access code. I love [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html) / [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock). If, however, you want to write an "integration test", @Hans has the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you could just write a unit test that first stores some `Items`, then in the same test, retrieve the `Items` and make sure that what you got back was "equivalent" to what you stored in the first place.

For instance (if I may venture a guess), it sounds to me like your `Itemmgr` class might be extended down the road to include volatile and persistent versions (maybe one version is in-RAM, maybe one is on-disk).  Your test could go so far as to make sure that `item1 == item2` returns true in the RAM-resident version, but `item1 != item2 && item1.equals(item2)` returns true in the persistent test to ensure that item2 was serialized or copied from somewhere and isn't just retrieving the original from a `Map` of some kind.  Just some ideas.